# Página carrega normalmente, mas com status 404

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Alguém já viu algo do tipo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
http://engenhariamrc.com.br/admin

É um projeto em laravel 5.7 hospedado na king host, o site está funcionando normalmente no servidor local, mas no servidor web ele carrega a página com o status 404 e por isso não consigo fazer login nem nada, esse é o terceiro servidor que eu migro

UPDATE
Não importa o que eu coloque nessa página ela sempre da o erro 404, eu já coloquei direto na rota do laravel pra retornar apenas "teste" ele exibe o teste com um status 404

Tenho alguns logs do apache que solicitei por chamado

Wed Nov 07 17:07:24.503040 2018] [core:info] [pid 116542:tid 140133659547392] [client 2804:14d:bad4:9daf:40d7:3cc0:9fd3:fbd:51362] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/engenhariamrc/www/admin/login

www.engenhariamrc.com.br 2804:14d:bad4:9daf:40d7:3cc0:9fd3:fbd - - [07/Nov/2018:17:19:05 -0200] "GET /admin/login HTTP/1.1" 404 1134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0" 51956

Comment: Olá! Verifique as permissões da pasta onde está o arquivo em seu servidor. Primeiramente faça um teste alterando a permissão da pasta para `chmod -R 777`

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro MEU DEUS VOCÊ É UM GENIO, tinha que ter o mesmo sobrenome, deu super certo, eu mudei a permissão da pasta public para 777, cria uma resposta ai para eu poder colocar como resposta correta

Comment: Não mude a permissão da pasta pública, e sim reveja a permissão de onde está armazenado o arquiv de login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá. Esse problema tem relação com as permissões da pasta onde está o arquivo de login. Primeiramente verifique qual permissão está setada na pasta, depois faça um **teste** alterando para `chmod -R 777`, porém verifique depois as permissões e tenha cuidado com a segurança. O correto seria você configurar todos os seus diretórios para `755` e seus arquivos para `644`

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado, eu só precisava achar o que causava o problema, agora vou configurar tudo certinho

Comment: @AndréMonteiro Boa!